# confused by integration constants in DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following coupled differential equations using `DSolve[]`

[image]

which has code

```
solution = Flatten[DSolve[{
     0 == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(a[z]\)\) + c \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(b[z]\)\) ,  \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(b[z]\)\) + c \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(a[z]\)\) == 0 }
    , {  a[z], b[z]}, z ]] // Expand
```

The solution is given by Mathematica to be
[image]
where you can see that if the solution is to remain bounded at $\pm \infty$, the integration constants `C[2]`, `C[4]` must all be zero (so solution ends up being a constant).

If I solve by hand, I get different integration constants (not necessarily identical) for positive and negative exponent terms which allows me to apply boundary conditions at infinity and the solution is not necessarily constant.

Is `DSolve` doing this right or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MichaelE2  I suppose that has to do with there being only derivative terms in the ODEs. However if I add a non-derivative term like ```solution = Flatten[DSolve[{
          0 == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(a[z]\)\) + c \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(b[z]\)\) ,  \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(b[z]\)\) + c \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(a[z]\)\) - \[Lambda] b[z] == 
      0 }
        , {  a[z], b[z]}, z ]] // Expand```, I dimension four for the $b$ solution but I still have the same issue with boundendness.

Comment: `DSolve` seems right to me. The eigenvalues are `{0, 0, -c, c}`. If `c` has a nonzero real part, then the corresponding basis functions each go to infinity at either plus or minus infinity. If `c` is pure imaginary, then there are other bounded solutions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I should have specified: $c$ is real (let's say > 0 too). My conundrum is that I want a solution for $z>0$. To avoid the solution blowing up I need to throw away c2 and c4 which kills the $exp(- c z)$ dependence too -- so I'm left with constant solutions.

Comment: What happens if you set `C[2]` and `C[4]` equal? (`solution /. C[4] -> C[2]`)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, I see what that does. For my specific situation, there's another work around where I can solve the first equation (using DSolve) for  b and then use that b to solve the second equation for a. That gives the more conventional expectation for general solution to a 2nd order diff. eq.